# 5 digit number divisible by 3 with 6 in it

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of 5 digit numbers divisible by 3 and number 6 in it?

I have been thinking of counting all 5 digit numbers that have 6 in it and divide it by 3. But I do not think it'll give the right answer.

In the other hand I have been thinking about sums of those numbers: 6, 9, ..., 42 - to analyze every single of them (6 = 6 + 0, 9 = 6 + 3 = 6 + 1 + 2 = ...)
But this method would require a lot of time?

Could I get some help?:D

Comment: Do you know that the sum of the digits must be divisible by $3?$

Comment: Try to find a recursive formula for the number of n-digit numbers divisible by 3 and NOT containing digit 6.